# Nextjs 13: Website icon and site name on search results

Tags: next.js, seo, metadata, next.js13

I am trying to set my website's icon and site name that appear on the google search results.

For example here, the `site name` is `Stack Overflow`

[image]

How can I do that using Nextjs 13's Metadata?

Here's what I tried in the `layout.tsx` file, but it didn't work :

```
export const metadata = {
  title: pageMetadata.title,
  description: pageMetadata.description,
  icons: {
    icon: '/icon.png',
    shortcut: '/shortcut-icon.png',
    apple: '/apple-icon.png',
  },
  openGraph: {
    title: pageMetadata.title,
    description: pageMetadata.description,
    siteName: pageMetadata.siteName,
  },
  ...
}
```

Comment: It may be because of the cache of Google if have added these metadata recently. Check your website with something like https://www.heymeta.com/

Comment: That would be very helpful for testing, Thanks

Comment: Your favicon must be a multiple of 48px square, for example: 48x48px, 96x96px, 144x144px and so on. SVG files don't have a specific size. Any valid favicon format is supported. From: https://developers.google.com/search/docs/appearance/favicon-in-search

Comment: I actually already did that (96x96) and I added the attributes `width` and `height` under `images`. but still no result so far

Comment: Im actually facing the same puzzle, am curious to know if some results popped up @oussamaZAAM